# Files not found after online sync

Tags: networking, windows-10, nas, offline-files

I initially turned on "Always available online" feature for one of my network folder. After turning it off, some of the files disappeared even though they weren't deleted. Why has this happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Sounds pretty vague. Is there anything you did before or after that might have affected it?

Comment: @NoahCristino when i turned on the feature, a duplicate folder was created. I deleted upon turning off the feature. I also removed permissions from "Everybody" before turning it off but then restored the permissions back.

Comment: It is still not clear what exactly you are trying to fix.  If you disable the network share then of course files on the network share will not be available.

Comment: @Ramhound So basically I have a folder on the NAS which is accessible through a private network. This folder had say 40 files from which only 10 are appearing. Last week, I turned on the online sync feature but then turned it off. A duplicate file was created during the synchronization which I also deleted. This problem arose right after the sync feature was turned off and after I deleted that duplicate file. All of this was done right after a fresh install of Windows 10.